# Can all kinetic energy from a punch be converted into the internal energy? What about momentum conservation?

Tags: energy, momentum

I've found a solution for how fast you have to slap a chicken to cook it.

For example:

- ½m1v1² = cm2Δt
- m1 = hand's mass (5 kg)
- m2 = chicken's mass (2 kg)
- c = 4185 J/kgK
- Δt = 50 K
- v1 = ± 409 m/s

But I know collisions can be either elastic or inelastic. And the situation when both colliding bodies would come to a stop – all kinetic energy would change to internal energy – occurs only under specific conditions (e.g. the same mass and speed).

My question is whether the momentum conservation actually forbids all the kinetic energy to become heat in this situation.

If we consider our hitting the chicken on the ground an inelastic collision:

- m1•v1 = Mz•v2

where Mz is the Earth's mass including us and the chicken (5,9 • 10^24 kg)

then

- v2 = 1,4•10^(–22) m/s
  Kinetic energy the Earth gets
- Ek = ½Mz•v2² = 5,7•10^(–20) J

That means almost all the energy was converted into the internal of the chicken, but am I right that not all can be?

Comment: The mass of the Earth is so large that almost all of the energy can be converted. Momentum has to be conserved.

Comment: Use LaTeX to type the calculations. It is rather unreadable as it is.

Comment: FWIW, 5 kg is a rather large hand and 2 kg is a relatively small bird.

Comment: Physicists don’t use t to mean temperature.